# iOS - In App Purchase - auto renew subscription - How to get notified if the user cancel or auto renewable subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I am working on an app which has our own user database and cross platforms subscription.
and my questions are:

pre-condition: in iOS, user did login with username and did auto-renew subscription.

1.if user deleted the app, will it cancel the auto-renew subscription for the app?

2. if user cancel the subscription from settings or from itunes, how do we know which user canceled the services?(I dont have game center id). I would like to inform my server that this user canceled subscription.

basically, how do we know a user did auto-renew or canceled the subscription without opening app.  Is there any unique id in apple's receipt which we can get to validate the user id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a rough solution. Basically, when user subscribe from application, you should also send receipt to your own server, and then from own server use receipt to request from apple server for the status. This is for cross platform subscription. It is unnecessary for single platform app.

Answer (score 0):

Server notifications are now available.

How to enable them: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/enabling_status_update_notifications

How to set the server URL: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev0067a330b

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, yes, you should keep `base64` receipts on your server as well as `original_transaction_id` of each subscription to find this customer in your database, when you get cancellation notification webhook.

We have the same functionality implemented in our subscriptions revenue growing platform. Let me know if you have any questions.